# Computer restarts after turning on, then stuck

Tags: boot, bios, post

I encountered a strange problem with my computer a few days ago.
My computer suddenly turned off, then turned on again, then, after 1-2 seconds it restarted again, and it got stucked. The screen didn't turn on, the keyboard's backlights didn't light up, and it didn't react to power, or reset buttons.
Now when I turn it on, it restarts after 1-2 seconds, and then gets stucked. The fans are spinning like the CPU is not in use, the PC is working seemingly, but it is "freezed".

Unfortunately I didn't see what happened on the screen before it shut down for the first time, I was away, only heard what's happening.

What can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Try starting with a bootable USB.  If it does not start, get it serviced at a local ship.

Comment: I can't access anything related to software right now, there's no input, and no output.

Comment: Get the system serviced

Comment: Problem solved
The PSU's cable, which supplies power to the motherboard's upper part, around the processor, has fallen out. I noticed an unplugged cable when I was putting back the videocard (after cleaning it), but I didn't notice that a cable is missing from next to the processor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because No question left to answer